# How can I make a button who draws a line

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas

I want to create a button that draws a line (with canvas) in HTML. I already tried something with CSS ( with display:none ) but it didn't work. How can I make it?

Comment: Lookup event listeners for `click` and how to draw a line on the HTML 5 Canvas. I don't see why you are messing with CSS for this problem. Also you didn't show any effort that you tried... Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it -

https://jsfiddle.net/jadeallencook/wnhmgya7/

**HTML**

```
<center>
    <div id="myLine"></div>
    <br />
    <button id="myButton">
        Draw Line
    </button>
</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
#myLine {
    height: 1px;
    width: 0px;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s;
    animation: myfirst 5s;
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 500px;}
  }
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 500px;}
  }

#myButton {
    display: block;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        e1 = $('#myLine');
        e1.addClass('animate');
        e1.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            e1.removeClass('animate');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't the user ask to do this with a canvas?

Comment: I have a small problem : the button appears, but it does nothing. Can you repeat please the JS code?

Comment: Repeat? @IanDavidBocioaca

Comment: Sorry, the problem with the code was at me.. Anyway, your code helped me very much. Thank You!